# Restrisct and read static files in crm 2011

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

We have xml files which are placed in custom folder "XMLFolder" inside Crmweb of MS CRM 2011.we are reading these xml files in java-script(using DOM).
Now after IFD ,We are able to access these xml files directly through external url without authentication like "https://example.com/xmlfolder/xyz.xml
Is there any way to restrict these xml files from url but access from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put files inside the Dynamics CRM folders is not a supported customization.

Instead you can put them as Web Resources, you will still be able to read them by JavaScript and to access them will be required to be authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Is there any alternative approach without much modification as we have used above approach in many places and we do not have much time to replace the code.

Comment: I don't know any alternative approach for this situation

Comment: Did you put this folder in the ISV folder? Yes, it is marked as a deprecated feature in 2011 but it still works and is supported. If the files are in the ISV folder they should be secured - if they are not, I would be concerned that there is an issue with IIS/ADFS/IFD. @GuidoPreite is correct that putting them directly in the Crmweb folder is not supported and, since ISV is deprecated, the correct way to handle this is to use a WebResource.